# Accessing an outer local variable from an inner block having another variable with the same name

Tags: c, local-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int i = 1;
    {
        int i = 2;
        printf("%d", i);
    }
    scanf("%d", &i);
 }
```

I have two local variables with same name. Both have different values. The above program prints `2`.

How can I access `i` with the value with one?

Comment: You can't. If you want to access them both, use different names.

Comment: Use a pointer pointing to the address of the outer `i`. There is no other way I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a little change in your code,use integer pointer.As below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

 void main()
{
   int i = 1;
   int *p = &i;  //Address of i given to p(integer pointer)
     {
      int i = 2;
      printf("%d", i);
      printf("---->Desire value in inner loop i= %d<-----\n",*p);
     }
  printf("---->Desire value outside of loop  i= %d and *p= %d<-----\n",i,*p);
  scanf("%d", &i);
}
```

In above code integer pointer `p` having address of `i`.So whenever u want to access inside `inner` loop also you can get value of `i` using integer pointer. Simple is that !!

Answer (score 1):

C follows `lexical scope`. It means the name resolution of a variable is done depending on the location of the `variable` in the source code. The variable is resolved by searching its containing block, if that fails then searching the outer containing block.So,

```
{
   int i=2;           
   printf("%d",i);    //this i is the one you defined just above, inside {}
}
```

This next `i` would update the `i` you declared in `main()`

```
scanf("%d",&i);
```

which is this one,

```
void main()
{
    int i=1;
    ...
```

So, inside the inner block `{}`, you cannot access the outer `i`, since they have the same name, and during the name resolution, the inner `i` will be found(as first the inner block will be searched for `i`).

One way is to use pointers, as pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520463/1795279) answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This all about the lexical scope here -

```
int i = 1;
{                  // inside this you can't access the outer i as they have same name so it will be shadowed by inner one 
    int i = 2;
    printf("%d", i);  // this will print the value of inner i
}
```

Similarly you can't access inner `i` outside these `{ }` .

If you want to print outer `i` you can just put a `printf` after the above block ends or you can make use of a pointer like this -

```
  int i=1;
  int *p;             
  p=&i;
```

and print it .

Answer (score 0):

You should get acquainted with the notions:

### Local variables, scope, and duration

> Variables that are declared inside a function or block are local variables. They can be used only by statements that are inside that function or block of code. Local variables are not known to functions outside their own.